# Adding Time on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bash, time, clock, raspberry-pi

I'm running an application on my Raspberry Pi, which includes the following line in a shell script,

```
sleep 1800
```

It then occurred to me that the Raspberry Pi does not have a way to keep time. How can I go about adding a driver and/or an application to get time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Raspberry of course has a way to keep time - like every other CPU there are timers available which can maintain some level of precision in the short term based on the CPU and other clocks.

However, the Raspberry Pi has no way to *maintain real time when powered down*, which is likely what you are thinking. If you need to have real-world time, use NTP at startup to synchronize Linux's clock system to real time.

Comment: No, I just need it to execute a subroutine every half hour. Should I be fine?

Comment: Absolutely. As accurate as bash sleeps are.

Comment: You could also use `*/30 * * * * yourthing` if you run cron. Even if you don't sync the time, it'll still run twice an hour. The benefit over `sleep 1800` is that a long running subroutine won't skew the next run.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as per [Yann Ramin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14349927/341929), the only way the Raspberry Pi can keep time is by synchronizing with NTP at startup and there is no driver nor application that you can add to get time.

Still, if logging or keeping time when offline is what you're looking for, you may want to add a **Real Time Clock** chip, like

- the **DS1307** module — *[tutorial on adding a DS1307 based Real Time Clock to Raspberry Pi](http://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi/overview)*
- or this other **[Raspberry Pi RTC](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-real-time-clock)**, *based on DS1302 module*.

Answer (score 0):

Add a RTC (realTimeClock) to the pi. Ive used a rtc called ds1302 which easy connects to the pi via 3 gpios. I have created a python script for this clock. Connect it to 3 gpios (a clk, a I/O, and rst) it will set the rtc clock like this: rtc.py -set YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
Get the current rtc clock: rtc.py -get.
and to set the system time: rtc.py -ss.
Set the command rtc.py -ss into /etc/rc.local runscript and the system time will be set on boot from the rtc. If int. in using the ds1302. Give me a holla for the rtc.py script, then i will github it!